# Error trying to create new react native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm

When i try to create a new react native project a i got this error

```
error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\AT140519\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-2wFpDD\node_modules\react-native\template.config'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\template.js
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\index.js
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\index.js
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js
- c:\Users\AT140519\node_modules\react-native\cli.js
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the `react-native` package but seems it's not installed.

Try running `npm i react-native`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still have the same error